# Is there a way to get the total size of files transferred to a page in real time using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, connection, filesize

I am looking for a way to know **how many KB of information have been transferred as a web page loads**. It would be nice for example to say:

loadedSoFar = window.document.loadedKB;

Two prospective uses would be to test connection speed or to draw a progress bar.

The Mac has the Activity Monitor application that can give network usage.

Essentially what I am looking for is network usage information in realtime via Javascript.

**Is there any such tool or function?**

Ideally it would work without my having to calculate the file sizes of all the page components.

Comment: There is a good article about ways to approach this problem at http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/analyzing-network-characteristics-using-javascript-and-the-dom-part-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.

JavaScript doesn't have access to network traffic like that.

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose is for providing a loading bar or a measure of throughput, you could prime the client with file stats. Most minimally, if your script is allowed to "discover" the nodes responsible for loading each file and watch their load events, or if the script can be made directly responsible for file loads, you can at least show progress on files loaded over total files.

Beyond that, and for more detailed stats, you could prime the script with a profile of the files to load, accounting for gzip compressed sizes. That would allow you to show an average throughout as files trickle in.